# Proof that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of $G$ such that the identity element $1\in S$. Assume that the subsets $aS:=\lbrace as \ |\ s\in S \rbrace\subset G$ for $a\in G$ form a partition of $G$. Prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I'm having some difficulty with this proof. I haven't really gotten anywhere with this question. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

Let $s,t \in S$. Note that $st \in sS$ and $st = st1 \in (st)S$. Thus because we have a partition, this implies that $sS = (st)S$. In particular, there is $r \in S$ such that $sr = sts$. Canceling $s$ from the left implies $ts = r \in S$, showing closure under multiplication.

Similarly, $s \in sS$ and $s \in S$ so we get $sS = S$, so there is $a \in S$ with $sa = 1$. Canceling $s^{-1}$ from the left implies $s^{-1} = a \in S$, showing closure under inverses.

Hence, $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Every partition of a set defines an equivalence relation among the elements of the set (and vice versa).

For any $a \in G$, the subset $aS$ is the equivalence class of $a$ ($a \in aS$ because $1\in S$) induced by the equivalence relation $b \sim a \iff a^{-1}b \in S$. If $a \in S$, then $S$ is the equivalence class made of the $b$ such that $a^{-1}b \in S$; but $a$ is arbitrary in $S$, so $S$ is closed under inverses and it is a subgroup of $G$.